# How to use javascript for calling data from database to front page in ionic framework(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is my first project on the ionic tecnology.Im still learning but Im stuck in one place.In js page, I creating repetitive page for listing films.I want to create one sample structure for ths page.And all films should be repetitive.

**movie.picture**, **movie.title and **movie.rating** I added these thigs but I cant get their values on the js and data service sides.Im confuse js and data service parts.I need basic examples :) how can I get those values?(by the way sorry for my bad language )

```
<ion-view view-title="films" ng-controller="filmlistcontroller">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list" ng-repeat="movie in movies">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/tab/film">
                <img ng-src="{{movie.picture}}" href="#/tab/film">
                <h2>movie.title</h2>
                <p>movie.rating</p>
            </a>
        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tutorial for this : [Try This](http://www.gajotres.net/creating-your-first-ionic-framework-application/)

index.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="films" ng-controller="filmlistcontroller">
<ion-content class="padding">
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/tab/film">
      <img ng-src="{{movie.picture}}" href="#/tab/film">
      <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{movie.rating}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</ion-content></ion-view>
```

filmlistcontroller :

```
.controller('filmlistcontroller', function($scope,$http ) {  $http.get('URL')
.success(function (response) {
  $scope.movies = response;
  console.log("$scope.productInfo :"+JSON.stringify($scope.movies));
}).error(function(){
})});
```

hope this will help you.